# How to add lowercase indexing to snowball analyzer for ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the default snowball analyzer in ElasticSearch

```
indexes :theme do
  indexes :name, analyzer: 'snowball', index: "not_analyzed"
end
```

Now i'd only like the server to index 'themes' as **lowercase**.

I should be able to this with `"filter": "lowercase"`, but i do not know how to add this to the existing :snowball".

Comment: I believe the snowball analyzer already uses "lowercase" filter, like many other out-of-the-box analyzers: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/analysis/SnowballAnalyzerProvider.java#L47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first create a settings over the index and you can specify the filter through this settings in your mapping.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/index_name' -d '{
"settings" : {
    "index": {
      "analysis" : {
        "analyzer" : {
          "lowercaseAnalyzer": {
            "type": "snowball",
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "language" : "English", 
            "filter": ["lowercase"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
}'
```

Now try applying this settings to your field in the mapping

```
                 "name":{
                    "type":"string",
                    "analyzer":"lowercaseAnalyzer"
                 }
```

Comment: Im sorry i was not able to understand about what filter you meant in your earlier post. Anyways you are welcome.

Comment: the JSON is missing a comma, but stack overflow won't permit less than 6 character edits.